# exponential limit of experiments

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to understand the theory of "limits of statistical experiments" as explicated in Chapter 9 of Van Der Vaart's text, "Asymptotic Statistics". For some models, the limiting experiment is non-normal, such as when the experiments are uniform with non-common support. The key theorem is that they converge to an exponential experiment:
[image]
(The footnote is that $P_\theta$ may be defined arbitrarily for $\theta<0$.)
For certain statistics, such as the largest order statistic, this makes sense to me, it is known to have an exponential type of limit. But what if I am just looking at an average. For example in the $nth$ experiment, where the observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid uniform on $(0,\theta-h/n)$, I take their average and normalize it, $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\theta/2)$. (I believe this is a valid statistic in this setup because the parameter is technically $h$, not $\theta$, as he discusses in other examples.) This sequence of statistics should be asymptotically normal.

But then the limit should have a distribution in the limiting experiment:
[image]
Does it follow that the normal distribution can be represented as a randomized statistic in the exponential experiment, that is, as some function of a shifted exponentially distributed random variable $Z$ and an independent uniform random variable? I guess this is technically possible by ignoring $Z$ and applying $\Phi^{-1}$ to the uniform...But I still can't reconcile his remark quoted above that a "normal approximation is impossible". Or am I misunderstanding the theorems?

Comment: There is a marker for a footnote to Theorem 9.6.  Can you please add the footnote and any surrounding context necessary to understand the content of the theorem.

Comment: @Ben I added the footnote. As to context, I would like the question to be more self-contained but I'm not sure how much to add. I did include everything preceding the theorem in that section. The material leading up to that section is the somewhat involved and technical motivation for "limits of statistical experiments".

Comment: Given the potential ambiguity in the meaning of some terms in the theorem (i.e., is he referring to convergence of some *estimator* in the model?) it would be useful to show us the proof of the theorem used in the book.  The proof is likely to elucidate the author's intended meaning in the theorem.  Can you please add this (if it is not too long)?